# Display the list of all songs whose duration is same as the song title "Lahor" (without subquery)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi i want to show same duration songs related to one song it's possible without subquery
Below code just shows only one song with SongTitle name->

```
SELECT SongsTitle
FROM Songs
WHERE SongsTitle='Lahor'
```

how to show songs that same duration like 'Lahor' song

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With one select I dont think its possible. Please try like this -

```
SELECT x.* FROM Songs S
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT S1.*
    FROM Songs S1       
    WHERE S1.SongsDuration = S.SongsDuration
)x
WHERE S.SongsTitle='Lahor'
```

Comment: Thank you it's working great. Can suggest any best source to learn advance programming like this. I want to understand it deeply

Comment: Please try this website - https://msbiskills.com/tsql-puzzles-asked-in-interview-over-the-years/

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible without a subquery:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM Songs s JOIN
     Songs sl
     ON sl.SongsTitle = 'Lahor' AND
        sl.duration = s.duration;
```

(If you don't want "Lahor" in the result set you need to filter it out.)

Personally, I think the methods with the subquery are easier to follow.

Comment: Thank you Gordon Linoff this one is very easy to read and use.